# Fingerprint reader supported, but not working (20.10)

Tags: usb, 20.10, fingerprint-reader

I have a plugin usb fingerprint that is listed with `lsusb` as `04f3:0c3d Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint`. When I first tried it out, I found out it wasn't in the list of supported devices at https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html, but now it is in the list.
However, when I go to the user settings, the fingerprint login option doesn't appear.
Do you know what could the problem be?